Using each delayed flop states in chisel ShiftRegister
I am writing chisel for the following FIR circut (specifically to understand ShiftRegister in chisel as this can be done easily using NextReg in chisel).

I have written this code:
class My4ElementFir(b0: Int, b1: Int, b2: Int, b3: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })
  
  val inDelayOne = ShiftRegister(io.in, 1)
  val inDelayTwo = ShiftRegister(io.in, 2)
  val inDelayThree = ShiftRegister(io.in, 3)

  io.out := (b0.U * io.in) + (b1.U * inDelayOne) + (b2.U * inDelayTwo) + (b3.U * inDelayThree)
}
println(getVerilog(new My4ElementFir(1,2,3,4)))

From the netlist, it looks like ShiftRegister is hiding the internal delayed flops  as they are unnecessary in this case.

My question is, can we somehow use the internal delayed flops states instead of multiple ShiftRegister objects for this case?

Use util.ShiftRegisters (ending with an “s”) instead.
Unfortunately I was not able to find any documentation for it but it’s fairly obvious from the source code:
https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel/blob/0f2efb52a78be5484fa231d5d635ce0a4b124bd8/src/main/scala/chisel3/util/Reg.scala#L98
Here’s an example usage from chisel tests:
https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel/blob/0f2efb52a78be5484fa231d5d635ce0a4b124bd8/src/test/scala/chiselTests/util/RegSpec.scala#L101

Resolved by using ShiftRegisters (ending with an “s”)
import chisel3.util.ShiftRegisters

class My4ElementFir(b0: Int, b1: Int, b2: Int, b3: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })

  var inDelays = ShiftRegisters(io.in, 3)

  io.out := (b0.U * io.in) + (b1.U * inDelays(0)) + (b2.U * inDelays(1)) + (b3.U * inDelays(2))
}
println(getVerilog(new My4ElementFir(1,2,3,4)))

Here is the netlist.

